# Regex for fixed string followed by characters up to a delimiter character

Tags: python, regex

I've exhausted myself trying to build either the right regex or just to remove the comma from the file that I"m parsing. Essentially, I am matching a specific string, then anything that follows that string, up to the comma.  I need up to get the substring before the comma, not including the comma. I suppose I can do this either with the regex or remove the comma further down in the code.

I'm pretty new at this, so probably basic stuff, but can't seem to find the right thing in my searches

Here is my code:

```
import re

str = "FullName=TECIBW04 TECIBW04, TargetResource=k2vFe6yPvBoEdrmrE9t3i5UE2muLVW,"

match = re.search(r'FullName=.+?,', str)


if match:
    print match.group()  ##'found a match'
else:
    print 'ainnussin zer'
```

I get:

```
FullName=TECIBW04 TECIBW04,
```

Great...I'm getting back what I need (and a little extra). I actually don't want the comma.

What's the best method to get rid of or not include that sucker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place what you want to match inside of a capturing group.

```
m = re.search(r'(FullName=.*?),', str)
if m:
   print m.group(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since, comma `,` is the delimiter here, just negate it in your regex as

```
match = re.search(r'FullName=[^,]+', str)
```

Comment: Good, but get rid of the `?`.  The whole point of using `[^,]+` is that the normal, greedy behavior of `+` is exactly what you want.  You don't have to sneak up on the comma to avoid overrunning it.  The way you have it (`[^,]+?`), the regex will never consume more than one character after the comma.

Comment: @AlanMoore, thanks for your insights. Being non-greedy did indeed broke the regex. I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

Put everything except comma in a saving group:

```
match = re.search(r'(FullName=.+?),', str)

if match: print match.group(1) ##'found a match' else: print 'ainnussin zer'
```

prints

```
FullName=TECIBW04 TECIBW04
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using `split` on `,`?

```
str.split(',')[0]
```

**Edit**

These are ways to do it without the regex.

For checking if the string starts with another substring, you can use

```
if str.startswith("FullName="): 
    print str.split(',')[0]
else:
    print "ainnussin zer"
```

For doing this in one line, you can try

```
print str.split(',')[0] if str.startswith("FullName=") else "ainnussin zer"
```

Comment: Why add an additional step and check if it can be done via just regex?

Comment: @alecxe Maybe not the optimal way, just another approach to doing the whole thing without regex, since I think OP is asking if he can do it in other ways (remove the comma further down in the code`)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use str.partition:

```
>>> str = "FullName=TECIBW04 TECIBW04, TargetResource=k2vFe6yPvBoEdrmrE9t3i5UE2muLVW,"
>>> str.partition(',')
('FullName=TECIBW04 TECIBW04', ',', ' TargetResource=k2vFe6yPvBoEdrmrE9t3i5UE2muLVW,')
>>> str.partition(',')[0]
'FullName=TECIBW04 TECIBW04'
```

If you are going to use a regex, I would use this:

```
match=re.search(r'^FullName=[^,]+',str)
if match:
    print match.group(0)  ##'found a match'
else:
    print 'ainnussin zer'
```

Or this if you are just trying to capture the RH of the `=`:

```
match=re.search(r'^FullName=([^,]+)',str)
if match:
    print match.group(1)  ##'found a match'
else:
    print 'ainnussin zer'
```